# .net 5 не вижу в vs2019 16.8

Tags: visual-studio

Сегодня вышла .net 5 Я скачал установил SDK.
Обновилась VS2019 до версии 16.8

Но я в упор не вижу там net 5.0 в списке target framework.

Как сделать net5 доступный в VS2019 16.8.0?

Спасибо.

[image: Установки]

Comment: а `dotnet --info` выводит, что у вас есть 5-я версия?

Comment: также проверьте во вкладке Visual Studio INstaller - > Individual components что net5 стоит

Comment: @Exploding Kitten добавил картинку в пост. Пишет все есть.  Но вот в targeting pack 5ки нет. Соответственно проект в 5ку не могу переключить. Как вчера дома не получилось так сегодня на работе с утра все обновил и ситуация таже.

Comment: создавайте под 3.1, а потом переключайте на 5, на сайте MS есть инструкция подробная, а так просто платформу в настройках проекта переключаете и все работает.
в списке кстати есть, только по умолчанию пока еще не срабатывает видимо, хз почему

Comment: @Softovick Да так получилось .net5.  Оформите ответ я Вам засчитаю ответ.  И если можно дайте ссылку на эту инструкцию. Спасибо.

Comment: ну это для уже существующих https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio
а для приложений с нуля достаточно потом просто платформу в свойствах переключить

Comment: а ответ не буду оформлять, потому что мне самому кажется что это не корректная работа, видимо дообновят и исправят

Comment: @Softovick да, что-то вообще не так работает. В net core подсветка синтаксиса некорректно работает. Скажем так не работает совсем. Программа компилируется, но создает еще dll без которой не работает.  Видимо нужно не спешить переходить на 5ку. Я с core дел не имел еще.

Comment: С подсветкой синтакстса разобрался. Нужно очистить каталог %User%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.xxxx\ComponentModelCache после чего подсветка вернется.